# Is it necessary to have prototypal inheritance in JavaScript just so we can dynamically propagate new properties we add?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I have been brushing up on prototypal inheritance in JavaScript and I have a major question about its necessity. I am unable to grasp the reasons why it is very important. I have been running the basic code snippet shown below :

```js
function Employee() {
  this.name = "geetha";
  this.dept = "general";
}
Employee.prototype.designation = "nothing";

function Manager() {
  Employee.call(this);
  this.title = "mr";
}
Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);

var mark = new Manager;

console.log(mark.name);
console.log(mark.dept);
console.log(mark.title);
console.log(mark.designation);
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

In the above snippet, if I remove

```js
Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
```

I can see it only impedes me from adding a new property on the go for the "Employee" constructor such that it trickles down to the objects it is a prototype of. Otherwise, if I am content with the properties already defined, I don't really need to make "Employee" the prototype of "Manager". The constructor call of Employee from inside Manager would accomplish the getting of its properties. So am I missing something really important in this concept?

Thanks!

Comment: Your understanding is fine. I suggest you read this topic at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain for more clarity

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the line

```
Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
```

then you are not actually using inheritance. You are simply using the Employee constructor to initialise the variables in the Manager instance just as they would be initalised in an Employee instance.

The thing to note is this line

```
Employee.prototype.designation = "nothing";
```

If you do not use inheritance then the property `designation` will not available to Manager instances because it will not be in the prototype chain.